# How do I make my code run every 5 minutes?

Tags: r

I want to run my code, which is a **webscraping** code that get news headlines for me, every 5 minutes in R. I searched for some question like that but I haven't found any.

I was thinking about declare a variable and creating a loop, but it didn't work out for me because the code will run what... 100 times per second or some like that. It works but not the way it should. I just don't know how to make it work on a clockwise schedule. Like, when the time on the system hits 20:05 it runs the code. The next run should be at 20:10 and so on.

Comment: Does it have to be within R, or can you run the scraper "all the way through" (scraping, parsing, etc, saving to disk) and run it as a program? Then you could use cron (Linux) or another scheduling program to run your scraper whenever you like.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be in R. Thanks bro

Answer (score 4):

You could use an endless while loop with a wait command:

```
while(TRUE){
    // run code 
    Sys.sleep(300) // number of seconds to sleep 
}
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.sleep.html

Comment: Very ingenious solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using the package `purrr` to make your function execute "slowly":

```r
# Packages
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

# Normal Scraping Function
scrapefun = function(url){
  page = GET(url)
  
  page %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_elements("h1") %>% 
    html_text()
}

# Make it slow
scrapefun_slow = slowly(scrapefun,
                   rate = rate_delay(pause = 1),
                   quiet = F)

# Vector of URLs to scrape
urls = rep("https://rvest.tidyverse.org/articles/starwars.html",
           3)

# The `purrr` way to loop
map_chr(urls,
    scrapefun_slow)
#> Retrying in 1 seconds.
#> Retrying in 1 seconds.
#> [1] "Star Wars films" "Star Wars films" "Star Wars films"
```

Just set the `rate` to anything you want. As an aside, I created the package "scrapurrr" that includes such functionalities, you can find it on github.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a chron job, as the link below describes.

https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/cron-job

Windows Task Scheduler may be another option for you. I haven't used it in a while, and I forgot the frequency, but it may be limited to 1x per day. You can check it out and see what the options are.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10